# Need assistance with workflow rule criteria

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow, workflowrule

I have a scenario when a time-dependant workflow needs to be triggered when the case status is new and specific users with specific roles are logged in.

```
    AND(ISPICKVAL(Status, "New"),        
    OR(
        $UserRole.Name  = "Role 1",          
        $UserRole.Name = "Role 2",         
        $UserRole.Name = "Role 3",          
        $UserRole.Name = "Role 4",          
        $UserRole.Name = "Role 5",          
        $UserRole.Name = "Role 6"))
```

So basically when the status is new and some of the roles are logged in the time dependant workflow needs to be activated after 60 minutes.

In my case, I am using a custom field that is 5 minutes from now so I can test the scenario in the next 5 minutes. For the custom field, I am using

The formula for Trigger Time 05

```
=NOW()-0.038
```

What I am doing wrong?

Cheers 
Darko

Comment: I don't think you can use a formula field to decide when the email should be send? I think your formula is correct though, and if you have your time dependent work flow action go of after one hour, it should just work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time dependant actions have a specific behavior according to salesforce documentation. Please see [Considerations for Time-Dependent Actions and Time Triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null). In the Time Trigger Processing section we can read:

> Time-dependent actions aren’t executed independently. They’re grouped into a single batch that starts executing within one hour after the first action enters the batch.
>   Actual execution may be delayed based on service availability.

So even if your rule is valid it won't be executed at the specified time. And as in this case with a range of minutes it will be executed very far from when it is expected.